# How do I use a DataFrame to create a legend in matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

I have created a treemap with squarify and now Im trying to create a legend to display the data in the treemap next to the graph.

The built in legend function is not generating the legend I want (it is currently displaying the first column of my data frame and the indexes of each row) so I've been trying to play around with it without success. I would like the legend to be:

SKU Volume in Units

a 1

b 2

c 3

d 4

e 5

f 6

g 7

h 20

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import squarify
import matplotlib.cm
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#create figure
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(16, 5)

#set data values
data = [['a',1],['b',2],['c',3],['d',4],['e',5],['f',6],['g',7],['h',20]]
data_slice = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Atom SKU Code','Total Volume'])

print(data_slice)

#create color set
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=min(data_slice['Total Volume']), vmax=max(data_slice['Total Volume']))
colors = [mpl.cm.BuGn(norm(value)) for value in data_slice['Total Volume']]

#plot figure
ax1 = squarify.plot(label=data_slice['Atom SKU Code'], sizes=data_slice['Total Volume'], color=colors, alpha=.6)
plt.title("Volume by SKU (Units Sold)", fontsize=23, fontweight="bold")
plt.axis('off')
plt.legend(title='SKU Volume in Units', loc='center left',bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5),frameon=False)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out a way to do this.
I removed the label and used plt.table to create a my version of a legend.
Also leveraged the colors I had created to make the legend look nicer.

[picture: output with legend table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWequ.png)

```
def genereate_legend_table(ax,colors,no_of_skus_to_graph,data_slice):
# ___________________________________________________________________________________
# DESCRIPTION
# This functions generates a legend table to be plotted with the treemap plots

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# ARGUMENTS
# ax: subplot axis where the table is to be plotted

# colors: color list object generated by matplotlibs color library

# no_of_skus_to_graph: how many skus are being represented in the tree map

# data_slice: the data to be written in the table
# ___________________________________________________________________________________
# Create hex color list from normalized color object
hex_list = []
for n in range(len(colors)):
    hex_list.append(mpl.colors.to_hex(colors[n]))


# Create table object on desired axis
legend_table = ax.table(cellText=data_slice.values,
                          colLabels=data_slice.columns,
                          loc='right',
                          colLoc='right',
                          colWidths=[0.2, 0.2],
                          edges='')

# Change table text color
i = 0
while i <= no_of_skus_to_graph - 1:
    legend_table[(i + 1, 0)].get_text().set_color(hex_list[i])
    legend_table[(i + 1, 1)].get_text().set_color(hex_list[i])
    s = '¥{:,.2f}'.format(float(legend_table[(i + 1, 1)].get_text().get_text()))
    legend_table[(i + 1, 1)].get_text().set_text(s)
    i = i + 1

# Return table
return legend_table
```